Crystalline at $\ell=p$ implies unramified at $\ell\neq p$
Let $X$ be a smooth, projective variety defined over some $p$-adic field $K$. Is it true that if the etale cohomology $H^i_{et}(X_{\overline{K}},\mathbb{Q}_\ell)$ is crystalline at $\ell=p$, then $H^i_{et}(X_{\overline{K}},\mathbb{Q}_\ell)$ is unramified for $\ell\neq p$? If it is true, can someone provide a reference for this fact?

I suspect this is unknown without additional hypotheses. (It's OK for $i=1$ and should be OK when the cohomology is known to be automorphic).

@WillSawin Thanks for the comment! Can you give a reference, or a reason, why it should be OK for automorphic representations?

I think more precisely this is known for Galois representations arising from regular algebraic conjugate self-dual automorphic forms on $GL_n$ over CM fields (and thus, I guess, also over totally real fields). The most difficult step is compatibility of the local Langlands correspondence and global Langlands correspondence when $\ell=p$ which was done in this level of generality by Caraiani in her paper Monodromy and local-global compatibility for $l=p$.

This says that the Weil-Deligne representation associated by $p$-adic Hodge theory to the $\ell$-adic Galois representation arising from the automorphic form for $\ell=p$ agrees with the Weil-Deligne associated by the local Langlands correspondence to the local representation at $p$, which, by the easier $\ell\neq p$ case of local-global compatiblity, agrees with the Weil-Deligne representation associated to the $\ell$-adic Galois representation for $\ell \neq p$.

An $\ell$-adic Galois representation for $\ell\neq p$ is unramified if and only if the associated Weil-Deligne representation is unramified (inertia and monodromy acts trivially). If $\ell=p$, an $\ell$-adic Galois representation is crystalline if and only if the associated Weil-Deligne representation is unramified.  It looks to me like recent results in the non-conjugate self-dual case are more suited to proving the converse of the statement you want then the statement itself. See e.g. Ordinary parts and local-global compatibility at  $\ell=p$ by Bence Hevesi.

@WillSawin Thank you very much! If you think this is the state of the art, perhaps post it as anwser and I will accept it. (Mabye you can also give an argument for $i=1$?)
